# How to create a string adding a char by char

Tags: c

How can I construct a string just by adding chars?

I tried

```
char * string[100];
string[0]='a';
string[1]='b';
...
```

`printf("%s",string)` shows me only `a`, not `ab`.

I need the string as a char pointer like the example.

Comment: Did you add a NUL after the characters you care about?

Comment: Also, `char * string[100];` should be `char string[100];`. The former is an array of pointers and you're getting compiler warning after compiler warning if that's really your code.

Comment: Also, I'm going to go ahead and say that you're on a little endian system if you see a printout.

Comment: I have to handle arrays with a pointer to char. I understand that there is 2 ways to create "strings" in C. What do you mean by adding NUL? Im learning the lenguage. So i dont get it.

Comment: NUL is another name for `'\0'`.

Comment: So, you mean setting like string[3]='\0' ?

Comment: There are no "string as a char pointer" things. There are **only arrays of characters**. A string is an array of characters that is terminated by `'\0'`. If you don't have an array of characters, you're doing it wrong. You can allocate an array of characters with `malloc` but it is still an allocated array of characters. You can use a string literal, `"ab"` but it is an array of characters.

Answer (score 3):

Try following code.

```
char string[100] = {0}; // string: {0,0,0...}
string[0]='a'; // string: {'a',0,0,0...}
printf("%s\n",string);
string[1]='b'; // string: {'a','b',0,0,0...}
printf("%s\n",string);
```

1. C string ends with a `'\0'`
2. an alternative way to initiate string is `memset(string,0,sizeof(string));`

Comment: `memset()` is a waste. Just do `string[0] = '\0'`, nothing past `\0` will be used anyway and is always generally considered to be garbage, when you'll add a real string you'll overwrite those `\0`'s anyway and you should put `\0` at the end of the string explicitly instead of assuming that everything is already `\0`'s so memset has no value and could possibly be a bad idea because a newer programmer might get used to that and when they edit the string they'd think that it's okay not to put `\0` at the end of string and they'll wonder why the string that was supposed to be...

Comment: ... `Hi` for some reason is `Hillo world!`... That's of course assuming that there's a single buffer where all data is stored into before being printed. Use memset only when you want to dump the string. e.g. there was something like a password and not overwriting it with zeros would potentially leave majority of it in memory for a long time. But that's entirely different problem.